# With a non-default namespace in XML should every tag have a prefix?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xml-validation

I'm a beginner in XML.  I just studied namespaces, and I struggle a little bit so my question is in this example,

```
<s:root xmlns:s="help.com">
  <h></h>
</s:root>
```

can we have `<h>` without the `s:` prefix ?

If yes, is `<h>` included in the `s:` namespace or not?

I know is a dumb questions, but every one start dumb.  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Your question is not "dumb" at all — actually reflects advanced emerging understanding.</sub>

### "Should" XML

"Should" XML questions may be answered at two levels: [*well-formedness* and *validity*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

1. Your XML is indeed *well-formed*.  It follows all of the rules for
   being XML.  It even follows all of the rules for being
   *namespace-well-formed*.  Under the rules of XML well-formedness, yes,
   you can have an `h` element without a `s:` prefix.  (Under the rules of
   namespace-well-formedness, you can as well — you just couldn't have
   a `d:h` element with an undeclared `d` namespace prefix.)
2. Your XML may or may not be *valid*.  In XML terms, to be *valid*
   implies that it follows the rules given by a schema (commonly XSD;
   less commonly DTD, Relax NG, Schematron, ...).  Under the rules of validity
   given by an XML schema, you may or may not be able to have an `h` element
   in that position — we would have to have an XML schema to know.

### XML Namespaces

For your XML,

```
<s:root xmlns:s="help.com">
  <h></h>
</s:root>
```

- `root` is in the `help.com` namespace.
- `h` is in no namespace.

For this XML,

```
<root xmlns="help.com">
  <h></h>
</root>
```

- `root` is in the `help.com` namespace.
- `h` is also in the `help.com` namespace because `xmlns="help.com"` declares
  a *default namespace* that applies to `root` and all descendent elements
  lacking namespace declarations.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Yes, your example is well-formed.

(b) The `h` element is in no namespace. An unprefixed element is in a namespace only if it is within the scope of a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="some-url"`)

Answer (score 1):

Your example XML is valid so, yes, `h` element can be withou prefix `s:`, and it means that `h` is in empty namespace, not in the same namespace as referenced by the prefix `s:`. Descendant elements without prefix inherit default namespace implicitly, but not with prefixed namespaces.